# Can't get django-storages to set defaultStorage

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon AWS S3, and trying to set up my Django app to deploy on Heroku and set static and media files using the `django-storages` package (which also uses `boto`).

My settings.py includes the following:

```
DEBUG = False
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

if not DEBUG:
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    STATIC_URL = S3_URL
    ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'storages',
)
```

When I log into my console to see if the default storages are set, though, I'm not getting what I should according to the `django-storages` [getting started guide](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html).

Here's a sample from my shell session:

```
>>> from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
>>> print default_storage.__class__
<class 'django.core.files.storage.DefaultStorage'>
```

According to the guide, I should have got this back:

```
>>> from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
>>> print default_storage.__class__
<class 'S3Storage.S3Storage'>
```

I have tried importing my settings.py into the interactive shell. No luck. However, my other AWS settings are stored fine, such as S3_URL, which is retrieving the env variable and inserting into the amazon URL.

Can anyone give me a clue?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

have you installed boto? If boto is not installed properly, likely that django-storages will set you back to the default storage class if it could not properly import boto.

Comment: Yes, I've got boto 2.9.8 installed via pip.